# Getting undefined while using eventListner in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I want to add class `active` to div with className `box1`, when I click on div with className `box1`. But I am not able to understand how to do that.

My current code:

```
import React from 'react';
import data from './content/data';

const List = () => {
    const handleClick = () => {
        console.log(this);
    };

    let listItem = data.map(({ title, src }) => {
        return (
            <div
                key={src}
                className='box1'
                onClick={handleClick}
            >
                <img src={src} title={title} align="center" alt={title} />
                <span>{title}</span>
            </div>
        );
    });
    return <div className="container1">{listItem}</div>;
};

export default List;
```

Comment: What element are you trying to add a class to?

Comment: i want to add .active class

Comment: Arrow functions do not have a ``this`` value, so you cannot use it. You have two options: Use a regular function as the event listener and access the ``this`` value, or use the event passed to the listener

Comment: @Tracer69 even if i am using ```function handleClick(){console.log(this);}``` i am getting ```undefined``` in terminal

Comment: @andy i want to add class in div

Comment: You may receive ``undefined``, because react provides a custom wrapper around the dom events. Try using ``onChange={(event) => console.log(event.target)}``.

Comment: @Tracer69 then i will get the element ```img```, ```span``` or ```div``` depending on where i clicked. I want it to always return me ```div```

Comment: You have lots of `divs`. Some are being generated by `map`, and then you have a main one. Is your question "how do I apply a new class to the `div` that I've clicked on"?

Comment: @Andy i have mentioned in the question that i want to add class on ```box1``` when i click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `eventListener` is calling the function out of the render context, your `handleClick` wouldn't know it belongs to the `this` that you mean. Any part of your UI could have triggered that `eventListener` and called the function.

So you will need to use `useRef` to store any variables, or in your `handleClick` change the state of a `useState` variable, and then in a `useEffect` hook, deal with what you want to in context.

Comment: please give the answer

Comment: I did. If you want to change the class name on click, you could use a useState variable. Amit's answer is more than adequate, we aren't here to write your code

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the div store the title in state, and when you `map` over your array, check to see if the title matches what the state is and add a class accordingly.

```js
const {useState} = React;

function Example({ data }) {

  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

  function handleClick(e) {
    setActive(e.target.dataset.id);
  }

  let listItem = data.map(({ title }) => {
    
    const classes = ['box1', title === active && 'active'].join(' ');

    return (
      <div
        className={classes}
        data-id={title}
        onClick={handleClick}
      >{title}</div>
     );
  });

  return <div className="container1">{listItem}</div>;

};

const data = [
  { title: 'Bob' },
  { title: 'Sally' }
];

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example data={data} />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
.active { background-color: #efefef; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: bro why are you changing the question? I have childElement in side the div, where are they? If I only had single element then I wouldn't have to ask the question

Comment: It was a very bad example, I can also do that. Can you do the same thing with child element then tell.